# Is memory locked (pinned) or not?

Tags: macos, unix, memory-management, linux-kernel, posix

I am trying to set up for some performance profiling and also run-time decisions affecting buffering strategy.  My application receives a pointer to a buffer allocated by a library (CUDA or OpenCL).

**How can I test that a memory region is page-locked?**

As far as I can tell, POSIX gives us `mlock()` and `munlock()`.  How do I effectively check the fictitious `mislocked()`?

Answers for Mac OS X or Linux would be helpful.

I've seen several references, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736968/why-is-cuda-pinned-memory-so-fast) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978699/pinned-memory-opencl-has-anybody-successfully-used-it) that suggest the writers of driver libraries have figured out how to make this test.  How can I do it in my user code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/proc/$PID/smaps` contains "Locked:" line which should be enough for simple ensurance whether pages are locked or not. Otherwise see `/proc/$PID/pagemap` interface.

Comment: Finally able to test this on a linux system.  This is an OK approach.  Was hoping for something I could call more readily from my program, but I can work with it.  I'm just holding out a bit longer to see if anyone can suggest an OS X approach which does not implement the proc pseudo-filesystem.